# Getting a quarterly trend of sales from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How would I get the quarterly `(3 months)` trend of sales from my `mysql` db in codeigniter?

I have a data table

```
order
-id
-paid_date
-order_total
```

The data I would like to receive is the slope of total order values as opposed to simply the number of orders on the past 3 months.

**Model code**

```
$results = $this->db->query("SOME_SQL");
```

Ive started writing the below but stumped at how to show the results as a slope
::where 90 represents roughly 3 months

```
    $day_seconds = 86400;
    $period = 90 * $day_seconds;

    $this->db->select('COUNT(*) AS total', false);
    $this->db->select("FROM_UNIXTIME(`paid_date`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date", false);
    $this->db->where('paid_date >', time()-$period);
```

**Example expected output**

The output should only be 2 values to show a trend.

```
$results = [ [ 0 => 44 ], [1=>88] ];
```

Ideally want is needed is to know if the total earning of sales is sloping up, or down, a higher positive slope indicate a large increase of sales

Ex:

```
//Dramatic Increase of sales
$results = [ [ 0 => 22 ], [1=>150] ];


//Slow Increase of sales
$results = [ [ 0 => 50 ], [1=>55] ];

//Slow Decrease of sales
$results = [ [ 0 => 64 ], [1=>55] ];
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Can you tell us with words please?

Comment: ok ill update my question, but basically I want to know if the total revenue is sloping UP or DOWN in the past 3 months

Comment: compared to the 3 months before the last 3 months?

Comment: If possible yes that would work, or compared to weekly sales. But yes tats a good point. Compared to the previous quarter

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *, 
    CASE WHEN last_3 > prev_3 THEN
        'sales up'
    ELSE
        'sales down'
    END AS sales_change,
    (
       CONCAT(((last_3 - prev_3) * 100) / last_3, '%')
    ) AS precentage_change
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(order_total) AS last_3
        FROM
            TB
        WHERE
            paid_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    ) AS tb1,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(order_total) AS prev_3
        FROM
            TB
        WHERE
            paid_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
        AND paid_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
    ) AS tb2
```

This should give you 4 values:

- last_3 - the sum of orders in the last 3 months
- prev_3 - the sum of orders in the 3 months before that
- sales_change - text when sales are up or down in the past 3 months
- precentage_change - numeric value (with %) to show the change in sales in precentages between last 3 months and 3 months before that

Using the INTERVAL in mySQL you can adjust it to your need using days or weeks

```
INTERVAL 1 DAY
INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Comment: This is the result I get 
    `
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[228]
          public 'last_3' => string '12.65' (length=5)
          public 'prev_3' => null
          public 'sales_change' => string 'sales down' (length=10)
          public 'precentage_change' => null`

prob becuase I have no data for the prev 3 months.
But it looks good :)

Comment: Didn't understand - do you still have an issue with the query? if it works accept it as an answer